# C++Builder (or Delphi) How to get font name and size of a themed Item?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

How do you get font name and size of a themed item? For example, a TMenuItem.

NOTE: Using TStyleManager::ActiveStyle->DrawText function is not an option for me. I want an actual font name.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-getthemefont?

Comment: Wait... Are you talking about Windows themes (like Luna or Aero) or VCL styles?

Comment: VCL Styles of course